# create service for search Items in list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a list of data and i show it in the tabel :

```
    <table style="width: 100%;border:2px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>Avatar</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Get Detail in Model</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  <input [(ngModel)]="idSearch" placeholder="Id" /></td>
    <td>  <input [(ngModel)]="nameSearch" placeholder="Name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of usersList ">
    <td><img [src]="item.picture" /></td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td><a (click)="GetDetail(item._id)">Detail</a></td>
    <td><a (click)="Delete(item)">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my service for get items :

```
  GetUsers(): Observable<any> {
return this.httpClient.get<any>('../resources/users.json').pipe(
  map(res => {
    if (res) {
      return res;
    }
    return null;
  })
)
```

}

now i want to create a component for search in the list , when user fill the input and click on the search button the list must be refreshed .

this is [Demo of my Issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbw1xb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-manager.service.ts)

**how can i solve this problem ????**

Comment: What is the search criteria? Which key's value should you search in JSON?

Comment: @AshishRanjan i must search user with name

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I have changed a few things there

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the fetched JSON to filter component as Input and also have the service injected there, incase the input is not received, you can call the service there itself.

After filtering the data, pass the filtered data to App Component.

Filter Comp.html

```
<button (click)="search()">Search</button>
```

Filter comp.ts

```
export class SearchByFilterComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() userList: any[];
@Output() filteredList = new EventEmitter();

searchName:string = '';
  constructor(private userService: UserManagerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  search() {
    if (this.userList) {
      this.filter();
    } else {
      this.userService.GetUsers().subscribe(data => {
        this.userList = data;
        this.filter();
    })
    }
  }

  filter() {
    if (this.userList) {
      const filteredData = this.userList.filter(ob => {
        return ob.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchName.toLowerCase());
      });
      this.filteredList.emit(filteredData)
    }
  }

}
```

App.html

```
<app-search-by-filter (filteredList)="updateList($event)" [userList]="usersListToSend"></app-search-by-filter>
```

App.comp.ts

```
usersListToSend: any[];
FetchData(): void {
  this.userService.GetUsers().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.usersList = data;
    this.usersListToSend = data;
  })
}

updateList(e) {
  this.usersList = e;
}
```

Above are the suggested new changes, the rest of your code remains same.

This filtering should ideally be done at the API level but since we have the JSON here we are querying the it everytime.